# Updating old formatted spreadsheets using a reformatted spreadsheet that takes the old values and duplicates them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

**CODE IS DONE** thx @TheMaster ✔

I'm an absolute novice in the google drive sdk, excuse me.

I'm trying to write a script, which allows many sheets that are identical to updated. Through a Source spreadsheet (with new formatting). Problem is that in the old sheets, values ​​are in there, which must be in the new sheet "Source spreadsheet" (with new formatting) in there. And then again and again with an old sheet reiterate.

Procedure in my mind for the script:

- <s>go to folder where many sheets are</s> ✔
- <s>open the first sheet and then always the next</s> ✔
- <s>take the data from area (A1:A2;C1:C2)</s> ✔
- <s>take the name of the sheets</s> ✔
- <s>Copy them into the data in the source spreadsheet in the same place</s> ✔
- <s>Make a copy of the source spreadsheet</s> ✔
- <s>Name the source spreadsheet as the old sheet</s> ✔
- <s>rename it and put it in another folder</s> ✔

I will help, where I can.

**current code**:

```js
function UPDATE() {
  //LEGEND: o=Old, ss=SpreadSheet, sss=SourceSreadSheet, s=Sheet, n=Name//

  //---TAKE ALL OLD SPREADSHEEDS FROM FOLDER ---//
  
  //replace it with Folder ID where the old spreadsheets are in
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID')
  //takes all files in the folder and sets the variable file
  var files=folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) 
    {
  var file = files.next();

  //---TAKE DATA---//

  //replace with source ID
  var o_ss=SpreadsheetApp.open(file); 
  //replace with source Sheet tab name 1 to as much as you want
  var o_s_n1=o_ss.getSheetByName('tab name1');
  var o_s_n2=o_ss.getSheetByName('tab name2'); //optional
  //assign one ore more ranges you want to copy
  var o_range1=o_s_n1.getRange('A1:A2'); 
  var o_range2=o_s_n1.getRange('C1:C2'); //optional
  //Copy the values
  var o_data1=o_range1.getValues();
  var o_data2=o_range2.getValues(); //optional

  //---COPY DATA---//

  //replace with destination ID
  var sss_ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('destination ID');
  //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  var sss_s=sss_ss.getSheetByName('tab name1');
  //Area where to copy in the new sheet
    sss_s.getRange('A1:A2').setValues(o_data1); 
    sss_s.getRange('C1:C2').setValues(o_data2); //optional

  //closes the code until here first
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
          
  //---DUPLIKATE SOURCE SHEET AND RENAME IT AND PUT IT IN THE DESTINATION FOLDER---//
  
  //gets the sheet name from the old sheet
  var o_ss_n=o_ss.getName();
  //replace with destination Folder ID
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID')
  
  //Copy the destination sheet and name it like the old sheet
    DriveApp.getFileById('destination ID').makeCopy(o_ss_n,folder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try what you dreamt of and if you run into a specific problem, provide [mcve]

Comment: @TheMaster I have updated my code, I do not get the repeat function, do you still have an idea?
Would it be nice to work here with flush ()?

Comment: You'll get the folder first > then execute this function you wrote for all the files in the folder inside the while loop. See the first example [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)

Comment: @TheMaster 
Now he takes all the files in a folder and copies them but he does not take the areas from the spreadsheets. what's wrong here?
do you have to do that with an array?

Comment: @TheMaster The code works, but it does not take the Ranges from the old tables and copies them to the new spreadsheet. where exactly is the error?

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.flush() should be added before the copy(not after). `but it does not take the Ranges from the old` What do you mean by `ranges`? Are the values not copied?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, I also found out, the code now seems to work that way. Now it is possible to paste several sheeds with old formatting into new sheeds with new formatting with just one click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally Done** thx @TheMaster

```js
function UPDATE() {
  //LEGEND: o=Old, ss=SpreadSheet, sss=SourceSpreadSheet, s=Sheet, n=Name//

  //---TAKE ALL OLD SPREADSHEEDS FROM FOLDER ---//
  
  //replace it with Folder ID where the old spreadsheets are in
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID')
  //takes all files in the folder and sets the variable file
  var files=folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) 
    {
  var file = files.next();

  //---TAKE DATA---//

  //replace with source ID
  var o_ss=SpreadsheetApp.open(file); 
  //replace with source Sheet tab name 1 to as much as you want
  var o_s_n1=o_ss.getSheetByName('tab name1');
  var o_s_n2=o_ss.getSheetByName('tab name2'); //optional
  //assign one ore more ranges you want to copy
  var o_range1=o_s_n1.getRange('A1:A2'); 
  var o_range2=o_s_n1.getRange('C1:C2'); //optional
  //Copy the values
  var o_data1=o_range1.getValues();
  var o_data2=o_range2.getValues(); //optional

  //---COPY DATA---//

  //replace with destination ID
  var sss_ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('destination ID');
  //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  var sss_s=sss_ss.getSheetByName('tab name1');
  //Area where to copy in the new sheet
    sss_s.getRange('A1:A2').setValues(o_data1); 
    sss_s.getRange('C1:C2').setValues(o_data2); //optional

  //closes the code until here first
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
          
  //---DUPLIKATE SOURCE SHEET AND RENAME IT AND PUT IT IN THE DESTINATION FOLDER---//
  
  //gets the sheet name from the old sheet
  var o_ss_n=o_ss.getName();
  //replace with destination Folder ID
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID')
  
  //Copy the destination sheet and name it like the old sheet
    DriveApp.getFileById('destination ID').makeCopy(o_ss_n,folder);
    }
}
```